# RODBC sqlQuery returns different number of rows every time I run it

Tags: r, rodbc

I have a simple SQL query that should return 74m rows. I know so because I ran the same query in SSMS using count(*). However, when using RODBC sqlQuery in R, it returned less rows and I tried running the same code many times and found that the returned dataframe contains different number of rows every time (ranging from 1.1m to 20m). I cannot replicate the sql query exactly here due to confidentiality but conceptually it is similar to the below.

```
con <- odbcConnect("db_name", uid="my_user_id", pwd="my_password")

df_2 <- sqlQuery(con, paste("SELECT *
                             FROM table_name
                             WHERE CountryName <> 'US' and Month in (1,2,3)"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Why would an exact same code return different results every time? I tried running this more than 10 times.

Comment: If data keeps changing with each call, then the table may be interacted by other users, processes, or apps beyond yourself. Check with your DBA or team.

Comment: The data doesn't change. In fact, even if I use count(*) in SSMS multiple times, I get the same number of rows every time

Comment: The [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RODBC/versions/1.3-15/topics/sqlQuery) suggest improving (driver-based) performance by changing either `rows_at_time` (at connection time) or `believeNRows` (at query time). I don't use that pkg (I'm using `DBI` and `odbc`), perhaps changing one (or both) of those can help.